# Using Background size cover property in the CSS to cover the entire available screen size without scroll left-right

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-size

Trying to fix the lower section, span with anchor text. But its not helping out! It is require to use the `background size:cover` property! I've used in the header and it seems working but the same is not working with the lower section.

[**Here Goes the GitHub Repo**](https://github.com/Prabhakarzx/PrabhakarAndAlex-Old-Apple.com-Clone/tree/feature-branch)

[**Here is old Apple.com Website from which clone is to be made**](https://web.archive.org/web/20140301004610/http://www.apple.com/)

**Here goes HTML:**

```
<main>
<div class="lowerContainer">
            <a href="#"><span class="lowerImage lowerImg1"></span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="lowerImage lowerImg2"></span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="lowerImage lowerImg3"></span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="lowerImage lowerImg4"></span></a>
        </div>
    </main>
```

**Here goes the CSS:**

```
span {
  display: block;
}
.lowerContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1445px;
  border: #fff;
  border-width: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.lowerImage {
  margin-left: 1.5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 364px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 190px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.lowerImg1 {
  background-image: url(../images/mobile-1.jpg);
}

.lowerImg2 {
  background-image: url(../images/mobile-2.jpg);
}

.lowerImg3 {
  background-image: url(../images/mobile-3.jpg);
}

.lowerImg4 {
  background-image: url(../images/mobile-4.jpg);
}
```

**Any Help will be greatly Appreciated!**
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try it this code to perfect view.

```
    background-position: center;
```

this CSS to set the position of images to display.

```
.lowerImage {
  margin-left: 1.5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 364px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 190px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mate!
Thank you for your efforts!
I tried adding `background-size: center;` But it didn't worked as expected! However it has been done collaboratively be doing some structural changes! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `width` of each span is `364px` so total width becomes `1456px` which is more then the `max-width` of the `.lowerContainer` that is `1445px`, so this can be the reason for left-right scroll.

Try to set the `width` for `.lowerImage` less, so that the combined width of all the `<span>` tags doesn't increases more than `.lowerContainer` max-width.

```
.lowerImage {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 360px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 190px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Dear Gagandeep,
Thank you so much for the detailed information!
I tried going through it!
But it didn't worked! Figured out another way! By doing some structural changes! Thanks for taking our time and it do help to understand the working!